# Need Assistance with Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Help!  I'm looking to create a formula that checks to see if cell A1= x AND cell B1=x then cell C1 will return a "Yes" otherwise "No", but if cells A1 is blank  AND Cell B1 is Blank then I want C1 to remain blank.

So far the formula I have is:

=IF((A ="X")*AND(B="X),"yes","No")

But my formula seems to be missing the blank syntax part. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You will want a nested if.

AND is not `A AND B` but `AND(A,B)`

```
=IF(AND(A1="",B1=""),"",IF(AND(A1="X",B1="X"),"Yes","No"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott. I tried your suggested formula, but it doesn't return a blank value if both A1 and B1 cells are blank.

Comment: Then the cells are not blank, they probably have a space in them.  How are they filled?

Comment: They are just blank formatted as "general". These would be manually filled-in.

Comment: Try deleting the values in both, not clearing with the space bar.

Comment: I cleared both cells by hitting delete and when I double click the cell and use the backspace key, it does not return a blank field. Cell C1 stays listed as "No"

Comment: See edit.  It is working for me.

Comment: Now it works!  Thank you so much!!! You ROCK!